# Can i have a infinite loop without crashing it?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, infinite-loop

I want to make this code infinite loop (i placed it in loop.js) without crashing the browser with a really short delay

```
player.style.right = (Number(player.style.right.split("px")[0]) - dx) + "px";
  player.style.top = (Number(player.style.right.split("px")[0]) - dy) + "px";
  if (player.style.right.split("px")[0] > 315) {
    player.style.right = 315 + "px";
  }
  if (player.style.right.split("px")[0] < -30) {
    player.style.right = -30 + "px";
  }
  if (player.style.top.split("px")[0] < 0) {
    player.style.top = 0 + "px";
  }
  if (player.style.top.split("px")[0] > 282) {
    player.style.top = 282 + "px";
  }
console.log(`dx:${dx}`)
console.log(`dy:${dy}`);
```

How can i do it?

Comment: Don't worry. You wont crash the Web. Just your browser. setTimeout or setInterval will be what you want

Comment: And the world wide web still exists

Comment: haha lol @JaromandaX the humor here, genius

Comment: Shh. Just git back from a 365 day ban here for trying to be funny!!! That's not a joke by the way!!!!

Comment: I'm misunderstood mainly. The moderators have no concept of the context of comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do an infinite loop directly.
But you can use `setInterval` to not block the main thread entirely.